# Preventing smoothing of TileImage layer

Tags: openlayers

I'm working in OpenLayers 4.6.5 with a Landsat 8 TileImage layer supplied by an AWS Lambda tile server (as per https://github.com/mapbox/landsat-tiler), and need to prevent the pixels in the image from being dithered/interpolated - such that each pixel (which is approx 30m high x 30m wide) contains only a single colour with no shading. Below is an example of what I'm seeing:

[image]

I've found a few cases where others have had the same problem with static PNG sources, and so I've tried the following javascript:

```
map.on('precompose', function(evt) {
  evt.context.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
  evt.context.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
  evt.context.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
  evt.context.msImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
});
```

... and the following CSS:

```
.tm-openlayer-map
    canvas {
      image-rendering: optimizeSpeed;
      image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges;
      image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast;
      image-rendering: -o-crisp-edges;
      image-rendering: pixelated;
      -ms-interpolation-mode: nearest-neighbor;
    }
```

But neither of these approaches seem to make any difference at all. I can only conclude that either these approaches don't work with TileImage layers, or that my tile server is actually supplying pre-smoothed images. Would appreciate any and all suggestions!

Comment: I've deleted my first comment as blurring was occurring due to zooming beyond the capability the layer when maxZoom wasn't specified in the tilegrid.  If the tilegrid resolutions and sizes in `ol.source.TileImage` correctly reflect what is being served and the precompose options are set there is no blurring or interpolation.  e.g. OpenStreetMap set up using TileImage pixelates (at least when using Chrome) on the lower map but blurs on the synchronised unadjusted top map when zoomed 5 levels beyond what is being served.  http://mikenunn.16mb.com/demo/smoothing.html

Comment: OpenLayers also defaults to 256 pixels.  I assume the tiles and the map view are using the same projections, so there is no reprojection issue?  It would also be worthwhile opening a single tile in your browser, save it and open in something such as Paint and zoom in to check that it's not a server problem.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my other comment as I'd misunderstood part of your comment and example. Thanks for your help - I've been able to reduce the blurring by increasing the pixel size by setting a maxZoom level, which is great. Now it appears to be just a matter of working out what tile size corresponds to 30m x 30m on the ground...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is an old question now, but I've finally been able to make this work, so I thought others might find this helpful.

Since OpenLayers [6.4.0](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/releases/tag/v6.4.0), you can disable image smoothing for a source (code sample below is from [this example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/disable-image-smoothing.html) on the OpenLayers website):

```
var disabledLayer = new TileLayer({
  // specify className so forEachLayerAtPixel can distinguish layers
  className: 'ol-layer-dem',
  source: new XYZ({
    attributions: attributions,
    url:
      'https://api.maptiler.com/tiles/terrain-rgb/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?key=' + key,
    maxZoom: 10,
    crossOrigin: '',
    imageSmoothing: false,
  }),
});
```

Note: Make sure you set `imageSmoothing: false` on the **source**, not the layer! It won't cause any errors if you set it on the layer, but it just won't achieve anything ;)

I've found that if I want the pixelation to work the way I expect it to, I need to set `imageSmoothing: false` on the source, then set `maxZoom` on the source to be less than what I've set as `maxZoom` on the layer and the view (e.g. `maxZoom: 14` on the source, and `maxZoom: 19` on the layer and the view). Then I get the nice solid blocky pixels I want, without any distortion or shading or incorrect values inside any pixels.

Finally, make sure that the `maxZoom` setting on your layer is the same as the `maxZoom` setting on your view, or your user will be able to zoom in too far and your layer will disappear.